# web scraping python with Beautiful-soup

Tags: python, web-scraping

Hi I am trying to scrape a list of doctors and their address however I get an empty list
I set a locator for the required fields and pages and classes for the process

here is my code :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page_content=requests.get('https://easy.co.il/list/Orthopedics/?c2=5405').content
#assign locators
class QuoteLocators:
    DOCTOR_LOCATOR='p.biz-list-name'
    ADRESS_LOCATOR='p.biz-list-address'
class QuotesPageLocators:
    QUOTE = 'div.biz-item '
#assign pages
class QuotesPage:
    def __init__(self, page):
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')

    @property
    def quotes(self):

        return [QuoteParser(e) for e in self.soup.select(QuotesPageLocators.QUOTE)]

#set parser
class QuoteParser:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Doctor  {self.name}, at {self.adress}>'

    @property
    def name(self):
        locator = QuoteLocators.DOCTOR_LOCATOR
        return self.parent.select_one(locator).string

    @property
    def adress(self):
        locator = QuoteLocators.ADRESS_LOCATOR
        return self.parent.select_one(locator).string

page=QuotesPage(page_content)

for quote in page.quotes:
    print(quote)

print(page.quotes)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data you see on the page is loaded from external URL via JavaScript. You can use this example to get names, addresses of doctors:

```
import re
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://easy.co.il/list/Orthopedics/?c2=5405'
c = re.search(r'var catid="(\d+)"', requests.get(url).text).group(1)
c2 = url.split('=')[-1]
api_url = 'https://easy.co.il/json/list.json?v=1.1&c={}&c2={}&listpage=1&lat=32.059925&lng=34.785126&rad=8905&mapid=0&viewport=desktop'.format(c, c2)

data = requests.get(api_url).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for l in data['bizlist']['list']:
    print(l['bizname'])
    print(l['address'])
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
לאון אורטופדיה
דרך זאב ז'בוטינסקי 127, רמת גן
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ד"ר חג'לה עראבי רמת גן
ישעיהו 24, רמת גן
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ד"ר לפידוס לב חולון
בית לחם 20, חולון
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ד"ר רונן דבי
אסותא, תל אביב יפו
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ד"ר איתמר בוצר
איינשטיין 40, תל אביב יפו (עופר רמת אביב)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thank you very helpful, can you elaborate on the api_url  , did you connect to the API ?

Comment: @zachi I observed this URL in the Firefox Developer Tools -> Network Tab (there are all URLs the page is making, one of theses URLs was this address with the data)